# Import errors in django app during runserver and test related to __init__.py

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.11.7 and this is my project structure:

```
> project1
    > app1
        >__init__.py
        >views.py
        >models.py
        >tests
            >__init__.py
            >test_*.py
> project2
    > app1
        >__init__.py
        >views.py
        >models.py
        >tests
            >__init__.py
            >test_*.py
```

I was trying to import models from project1.app1 into project2.app1 and even after providing the proper path using sys and os packages it wouldn't work when I would runserver. I found a solution which said to create init file at project level in both places.

So now the project structure looks like this:

```
> project1
> __init__.py
    > app1
        >__init__.py
        >views.py
        >models.py
        >tests
            >__init__.py
            >test_*.py
> project2
> __init__.py
    > app1
        >__init__.py
        >views.py
        >models.py
        >tests
            >__init__.py
            >test_*.py
```

And I could run my application from the browser. Then I ran my unit tests and again it couldn't find the models from the other project. On removing the recently added init files (reverting to the original project structure), the import error wasn't being raised. Is there some other solution by which I can runserver and test without the application throwing import errors due to the presense/absence of project level init file?

**EDIT**
I'm using the following code for import

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__,'../../../')))
print sys.path, '\n\n'
from project1.app1.models import UserModel
```

Error the import throws:

```
ImportError: No module named project1.app1.models
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information here. What imports are you trying to use? What are you setting `sys.path` to? When you say "it wouldn't work when I would runserver", what actually happended?

Comment: Django projects should be isolated from each other, so cross imports is typically bad practice. If you want to use the same app in two projects, the simplest solution is to just copy the files and folders between the projects. If you are using the same app in multiple projects, you could also consider creating a proper python package, [as described in the official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/reusable-apps/)

Comment: @Alasdair I've edited my post to answer your questions.

Comment: I would add the `project1` directory to the path instead of its parent directory: `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__,'../../../project1')))`. Then you can do `from app1.models import UserModel`, and you won't have to add the `__init__.py` files to the project directories.